# How to post a mosaic of an image gallery instead of the entire gallery inside a post'

Tags: images

I would like to illustrate my blog post with a bunch of pics. However, instead of posting an entire image gallery in middle of the blog and taking up a lot of space, I would like to just post a mosaic of the first few pics, plus a count of the total number of pics. Like this:

[image: mosaic of pointing to image gallery]

How do I do that? **Is there a plugin that can do that?** I think the DailyMail website did this until recently. Just a mosaic of first few pics plus the count of total pics - instead of actually posting a million thumbs inside the blog.